# Find the missing place

Tags: geography

Below is a list of ten places on earth, with one missing. Some names belong to multiple places on earth, so first find the geographical division that contains each place exactly once (for example, a country name), and then use only the ten places found in that division. Next, find one geographical attribute (for example, the population) of each place, so that if you take the first number or first letter of each place’s geographical attribute, in the order shown, it forms a familiar ten-character number, word or phrase. What is the missing place, and why? If more than one place could qualify as the missing place, then list the place with the largest population.

```
Hercules
Martell
Willowbrook
Cartago
? 
Westminster
Garnet
Oakville
Heber
Newark
```

You may give your answer using the template below, or use your own words.

- What geographical division contains each place exactly once?
- What is the one geographical attribute?
- List the attribute for each place (list ten things).
- What ten-character number, word or phrase is formed by taking the first number or letter of each thing?
- What is the missing place, and why?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

What geographical division contains each place exactly once?

> The state of **California**, USA.

What is the one geographical attribute?

> The **county** in which the city/census-designated place is located.

List the attribute for each place (list ten things).

> Hercules: **C**ontra Costa County 
>  Martell: **A**mador County 
>  Willowbrook: **L**os Angeles County 
>  Cartago: **I**nyo County 
>  *Fresno: **F**resno County* 
>  Westminster: **O**range County 
>  Garnet: **R**iverside County 
>  Oakville: **N**apa County 
>  Heber: **I**mperial County 
>  Newark: **A**lameda County

What ten-character number, word or phrase is formed by taking the first number or letter of each thing?

> **CALIFORNIA**

What is the missing place, and why?

> The missing place is **Fresno**, since it is the largest city in Fresno County, California, and Fresno County is the only one in California that begins with an F, which was needed to complete the word California from the first letters of the County names.

Comment: Nicely done, and fast!